# Will bug repellent repel deer?

Tags: hunting, bugs, deer, repellent

I was wondering whether the deer would be able to smell bug repellent if you are wearing some while out hunting.  Is there a specific type of bug repellent that can be used that is less likely to make deer shy away from the area?

Comment: If you can smell it, you can be sure the game can. What you really need is a repellent they won't mind.

Comment: @Kevin I'm a little more concerned that I cannot smell it and the game can.

Comment: Any specific animals we are talking about?  Deer, turkey...?

Comment: @ClareSteen Large game such as Deer

Comment: @ClareSteen actually turkey would be nice to know too.

Comment: @JLundberg - Turkey won't smell it. They have a very limited sense of smell, if any. It's mammals you have to worry about.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, deer will smell your bug spray.  Even if you use all the fancy scent-eliminating sprays, soaps, and clothing detergents they can still smell you if you are sweaty.  Most important is the wind factor:  Deer will smell you if they are downwind of you.

NRA hunting advice for first-time deer hunters:
http://www.nrainsights.org/Five_Things_fs.php.

I would say use the bug spray you would have used anyway.  Just make sure you carefully monitor the wind and plan your hunting spot carefully.

Answer (score 3):

During turkey season I practically bathe in regular deet based spray since turkeys can't smell. Thing is, this spring I had a deer walking around calmly 10-15 yards from me more than once. Can they smell it? Sure. Does it alarm them? Why should it? I would think only if they've made an association between it and danger.